# Unable to remove folder, even with `--force`, sudo not needed

Tags: linux, directory, rm

Trying to remove a folder:

```
$ rm -r folder
rm: cannot remove 'folder/subfolder/cifscaf6': No such file or directory
```

Doesn't work. Let's try with `-f`:

```
$ rm -rf folder
rm: cannot remove 'folder/subfolder': Directory not empty
```

I believe the `cifscaf6` file is produced by a Java application (that most likely was incorrectly shut down), some sort of temporary file.

How do I get rid of this folder?

**EDIT:**

Also:

```
$ ls folder/subfolder/cifscaf6
ls: cannot access 'folder/subfolder/cifscaf6': No such file or directory
```

Quite bizarre.

As per request from @mrc02_kr:

```
$ lsof folder
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/117/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
bash     21509 olavur  cwd    DIR   0,42        0 1973196 .
lsof    114490 olavur  cwd    DIR   0,42        0 1973196 .
lsof    114491 olavur  cwd    DIR   0,42        0 1973196 .
```

As per request of @Elias:

```
$ ls -la folder/subfolder
total 1024
drwxrwx--- 2 olavur [mount]    0 Sep  4 09:27 .
drwxrwx--- 2 olavur [mount]    0 Sep  4 09:27 ..
-rwxrwx--- 1 olavur [mount] 3508 Sep  4 09:12 cifscaf6
```

As per request of @rbanffy:
`mount` (gives among other things):

```
//[domain path] on /mnt/some_mount type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=[username],domain=[DOMAIN NAME],uid=1004,forceuid,gid=1005,forcegid,addr=[IP],file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,nounix,mapposix,noperm,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

and `cat /proc/version` gives:

```
Linux version 4.4.0-92-generic (buildd@lcy01-17) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #115-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 10 09:04:33 UTC 2017
```

Comment: Can you show output of `lsof folder` ?

Comment: `cifscaf6` might be a symlink, have files in it not owned by you or the `folder/subfolder` is not there at all.

Comment: What does ls -la folder/subfolder/ show?

Comment: What is the filesystem type and the operating system you are using? Are you using Linux inside a host OS such as Windows? Can you do a `mount` and a `cat /proc/version`?

Comment: @rbanffy I believe it is a Windows system mounted on a Linux system. Specifically, it is an Isilon server mounted on a Ubuntu server. I added the information you asked to the question.

Comment: Is CIFS the only option for mounting it? Can you mount the storage from a Windows machine and confirm the tree is the same viewed from the Windows machine? Even though the file name seems very ASCII, I've seen some odd file name shenanigans when sharing storage between Linux and Windows machines.

It could be worth a shot to try to mount it under NFS, as the semantics are less alien to Unix machines, and see if then the thing is deletable. In any case, whoever manages the multi-million-dollar storage box may have some insight on what is going wrong.

Comment: @rbanffy Yeah, I think I have to contact the people who administrate the system. Thanks for the help. I'll post the solution, if and when I have one.